# Sum from/to date

Tags: date, powerbi, sumifs

I have 3 tables, one with stocktakes conducted last year, one with stocktakes conducted this year and one with sales. All of them are joined by date to one table where I have dates.

Now the question is what can I do to get table with:

store name/ last year stocktake date/ this year stocktake date/ sum of sales from last year stocktake date to this year stocktake date.

If you choose store, than stocktake date from one table, stocktake from second table all looks good, the problem is that I can't get sales to show from/to.

```
C2Csales = calculate(sum(PP_SalesLessTax[SalesLessTax]),PP_SalesLessTax[date] >= [ly date])
```

[ly date] is just a measure with last year stocktake date

I have a feeling that this have to be very easy but have no idea how to get this work

thanks

daniel

Comment: Can you share your data model?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two tables to simulate years. You can have just one. The idea of last year should be calculated by a measure. If you have a complete date table with a day for each row without missing days then you can build time intelligence.
If I get you, you need something like this two measures:

```
Sales = sum(PP_SalesLessTax[SalesLessTax]
Sales LY = CALCULATE ( sum(PP_SalesLessTax[SalesLessTax] , SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( DatesTable[DateColumn] )
```

With this two measures you can take both of them on same visualizations to compare them.
The idea of having from and to can be solved on visualizations. The slicer with a date type column can create a range filter data that will apply for this two created measures.

Answer (score 0):

please see data model. It is a part of bigger model but I have trimmed it so it is clear what is this about.

[data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xskqx.png)

And here is what I need. Please see picture.

thanks for all responses

[result required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6PyG.png)